# Windows server - can't install any roles and features - some noise about powershell not having remote access or something

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

I'm running a Windows Server 2019 VPS and I seem to have a problem.

Whenever I try to install anything using the "Add roles and features" wizard, It fails. This is what it says:

> The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service is
> configured to not accept any remote shell requests

I went googlin' and found out that I need to make sure that "Allow Remote Shell Access" option in the local group policy editor is enabled.
It was set to "not configured". Well, I enabled it anyway, and then ran "gpupdate /force"

Nothing.

I'm going back to the roles install wizard thing, and I get the same exact error. I tried some other feature to install, but the same story exactly.

And I know for a fact that it used to work! When I first got my VPS configured, I was able to use this wizard and install things. Now, it suddenly stopped working.

I know it's a very general question, and there could be many causes, but I can't seem to find anything online other than the "Allow Remote Shell Access" thing.

Any hint in the general direction of the solution to this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what happens after running `winrm qc`?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Running winrm qc shows 'the client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request'. Possibly because server has multiple IP addresses? No resolution for me so I used Powershell add-windowsfeature

get-windowsfeature -name *web* lists the available IIS features by name

add-windowsfeature web-client-auth adds the security feature 'client certificate mapping authentication' for example.